Connecting Jetbrains Datagrip to DB2 Version 7.5 encoding error
I am new to this so excuse and obvious issues. The only driver I can get a successful connection with is the JTOpen driver. I assume this is because our database version is so old. Anyhow, whats strange is one schema has the expected results but the other schema has columns that give results in EBCDIC, i believe. See my screen shot.
I have tried all of the drivers and the different types and versions but only JTOpen works with version 10.4

Its an I series AS400 version 7.5

IBM i 7.5  isn't old...it's the latest version.

I have more details. Some of the tables are encoded with CCSID=37 and some are CCSID=65535. 37 are converting properly and the 65535 are not.

The schema you are getting funky data from has the character fields defined as CCISD(65535) aka "Binary data".
By design, the JDBC driver won't translate that to ASCII or whatever your local language is.
The right solution, is to ensure that your DB tables have the columns tagged with the appropriate CCSID.
But as a workaround, you can set "translate binary" to true on the JDBC connection to force it to translate the mis-tagged fields.

awesome. That fixed it. It sure would be nice if Jetbrains could provide such quick responses as you all!
